# Apache Spark Temp files Size on DIsk

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a setup where the incoming data from Kafka cluster is processed by Apache Spark streaming job.

Version Info :- 
Kafka = 0.8.x
Spark Version = 2.3.1

Recently when the capacity of Kafka cluster was increased(by adding new nodes) we suddenly saw an exponential increase in disk usage of spark clusters(most of the space was occupied by spark temp files)

I am not sure if these are related and wanted some pointers to address/debug the same.

As a precaution we have increased the disk space of spark clusters to avoid "No space left on device" error.

Comment: I suggest you go look into the "storage" pane in spark UI.  We had similar issue once when we forgot to unpersist some cached transformation on the stream. We ended up with thousands of cached rdds eating the whole cluster storage in hdfs.

Comment: Storage pane does not show any cached RDD's